# Can Azure Devops create folders and shares as part of a release

Tags: windows, azure, azure-devops

I would like to use Azure Devops to create folders and shares on servers and share drives.  The intent is to move away from having developers or IAM create folders and have the folder / share structure be part of the release itself.  This needs to include empty folders, shares on servers and on a shared drives and granting specific permissions to service accounts by environment.

As an example, a new data movement application requires a source folder, a destination folder and an archive folder.  Each of these folders is in a different location (system wide share vs server share) and has different permissions.  I would like to have the prod release of the application create these folders (only if needed) and assign them the correct read/modify permissions to the service accounts and IT support accounts.

All of my searches have yielded results on how to create/set folders in the Azure Devops workspace, not the greater IT environment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to set up your DevOps pipeline on a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

After that, every pipeline based on the agent should do operations as the administrator of the OS.

For example, I set up a self-hosted agent on my server, and put it to a agent pool named VMAS, then I write a YAML pipeline like this:

```
trigger:
- none

pool: VMAS

steps:
- script: |
    echo %username%
    mkdir "C:/xxxyyyzzz"
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

You can create the folder in the server with no problem(out of the workspace):

[image]

So if you can use command directly to achieve some non-interactive operations, then it is also possible to do the same thing via DevOps pipeline.